# The jsoup works fine in all the other devices but runs into an exception when i run the apk on a (android pie)

Tags: jsoup

The problem is the jsoup library runs into and exception while i execute the jsoup.connect(url).get() but works fine on other devices i get error only in android-pie

```
public static void scrape(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "webscraping is running\n");
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("my url"+con.integer_route+".php").get();
                con.latitude = doc.title();
                con.longitude = doc.body().text();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "exception is running\n");
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: What is  the error can you share it?

Comment: it goes into exception on executing Jsoup.connect().get as a result i cannot webscrape the latitude and longitude

Comment: Can you log the message ? `Log.d(TAG, "exception is running\n"+e);`?

Comment: good idea will try that

Comment: Cleartext HTTP traffic to url.com not permitted i got this error

Answer (score 0):

people , android pie has a security patch that basically allows only https not http traffic as a result you cannot use http://url.com you must use https://url.com or change the manifest file you can check that out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)